# configure.log issue when update ruby 1.9.3 from rvm

Tags: ruby, rvm

I have install the latest Xcode but this keep occurring. How could I solve this issue?

```
Fetching yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /Users/dmonkeys/.rvm/archives
Extracting yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /Users/dmonkeys/.rvm/src
Error running 'tar xmzf /Users/dmonkeys/.rvm/archives/yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz -C /Users/dmonkeys/.rvm/src ', please read /Users/dmonkeys/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p194/yaml/extract.log
Configuring yaml in /Users/dmonkeys/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
Error running ' ./configure --prefix="/Users/dmonkeys/.rvm/usr"  ', please read /Users/dmonkeys/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p194/yaml/configure.log
Compiling yaml in /Users/dmonkeys/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
Error running 'make ', please read /Users/dmonkeys/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p194/yaml/make.log


Database file /Users/dmonkeys/.rvm/config/packages does not exist.

Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/dmonkeys/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...

ruby-1.9.3-p194 - #fetching 
ruby-1.9.3-p194 - #extracted to /Users/dmonkeys/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p194 (already extracted)
ruby-1.9.3-p194 - #configuring 
Error running ' ./configure --prefix=/Users/dmonkeys/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194 --enable-shared --disable-install-doc --with-libyaml --with-opt-dir=/Users/dmonkeys/.rvm/usr ', please read /Users/dmonkeys/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p194/configure.log
There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
ls: /Users/dmonkeys/.rvm/rubies/*/bin/ruby: No such file or directory
```

Comment: what does  /Users/dmonkeys/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p194/yaml/make.log say ?

Comment: It says [2012-06-13 21:28:10] make  -j2
/Users/dmonkeys/.rvm/scripts/functions/utility: line 147: make: command not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like missing development tools, read output of (and follow instructions):

```
rvm requirements
```

Most important you need `make` you can get it with osx-gcc-installer.

For fresh installation an option would be also [RailsInstaller for OSX](https://github.com/railsinstaller/railsinstaller-nix/downloads)